# Identity makes every matrix invertible?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, matrices, continuity

I have found this in a proof and do not understand where this comes from:

If A is singular, then there exists $\delta \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \forall \epsilon\in (0,\delta): \epsilon \operatorname{Id}+A $ is nonsingular.

It sounds similar to some corollary from the definition of continuous functions but I do not see how to proof this.

Comment: Note that Alex Becker's proof does not require $A$ to be singular.  That is, the statement in your question is true for *any* matrix $A$.

Comment: @MTS Of course, when $A$ is nonsingular we don't even need to appeal to $\det(x\cdot \mathrm{Id}+A)$ being a polynomial; it suffices to observe that it is continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that a matrix is singular iff its determinant is $0$. Consider the function
$$f(x)=\det(x\cdot \mathrm{Id}+A).$$
Recall that this is a polynomial in $x$, so it has finitely many zeros, say $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. Let $x_i$ be the smallest positive zero of $f$. Then setting $\delta=x_i$, we see that for all $\epsilon\in (0,\delta)$ we have $f(\epsilon)\ne 0$, i.e. $\epsilon\cdot \mathrm{Id}+A$ is nonsingular.